# Compare rows in groups in the same data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lag

My data looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(
  customernumber = c("111", "111", "111",  "111", "111","222", "222", "222", "222", "222", "222", "222"), 
  ordernumber = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3"), 
  article = c("JeansA", "JeansA", "ShirtA", "JeansA", "JeansB", "ShirtA", "ShirtB", "ShirtB", "JeansA", "JeansB", "ShirtA", "JeansB"), 
  size = c("40", "42", "40", "42", "44", "36", "36", "40", "40", "38", "44", "36"), 
  returned = c("1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")
)
```

Output:

```
   customernumber ordernumber article size returned
1             111           1  JeansA   40        1
2             111           1  JeansA   42        1
3             111           1  ShirtA   40        0
4             111           2  JeansA   42        0
5             111           2  JeansB   44        1
6             222           1  ShirtA   36        1
7             222           1  ShirtB   36        1
8             222           1  ShirtB   40        0
9             222           1  JeansA   40        0
10            222           2  JeansB   38        0
11            222           2  ShirtA   44        0
12            222           3  JeansB   36        0
```

Now I want to mark all orders per customer, for which an article has been returned, but ordered again in the next order in a different size. Thus, all articles that are only exchanged and can therefore not truly be seen as a new order. So the end results is supposed to look like this:

Result:

```
   customernumber ordernumber article size returned changed
1             111           1  JeansA   40        1       0
2             111           1  JeansA   42        1       0
3             111           1  ShirtA   40        0       0
4             111           2  JeansA   42        0       1
5             111           2  JeansB   44        1       0
6             222           1  ShirtA   36        1       0
7             222           1  ShirtB   36        1       0
8             222           1  ShirtB   40        0       0
9             222           1  JeansA   40        0       0
10            222           2  JeansB   38        0       0
11            222           2  ShirtA   44        0       1
12            222           3  JeansB   36        0       0
```

I thought I could sove the problem by introducing a lag variable using dyplr (or data.table), but I only manage to lag the variable within the same group but I fail to lag it into the next group. This is:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(customernumber, ordernumber, article) %>% 
  mutate(lag_size = lag(size, order_by = article))
```

or:

```
df <- data.table(df)
setorder(df, customernumber, ordernumber, article)
df[,lag_size := shift(size), by = .(customernumber, ordernumber, article)]
```

I don't want to think about a for loop (not even sure whether it would solve the problem), since the data set is quite big and it will take for ages.And I am overall really lacking ideas. So any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

---

---

**AddOn:**

I stumbled into another issue related to this case. I only want to mark articles that have been orderer in another *size* in the next follow up order as changed and not if the same article in the same size has been orderer again. So the criterium for the variable changed would be:

Order n: returned == 1
Order n+1: same article, different size --> changed == 1 (otherwise changed == 0)

Here is the updated example:

```
df <- data.frame(
 customernumber = c("111", "111", "111",  "111", "111", "111","222", "222", "222", "222", "222", "222", "222"), 
 ordernumber = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3"), 
 article = c("JeansA", "JeansA", "ShirtA", "JeansA", "JeansA", "JeansB", "ShirtA", "ShirtB", "ShirtB", "JeansA", "JeansB", "ShirtA", "JeansB"), 
 size = c("40", "42", "40", "40", "44", "44", "36", "36", "40", "40", "38", "44", "36"), 
 returned = c("1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")
)
```

Output:

```
   customernumber ordernumber article size returned
1             111           1  JeansA   40        1
2             111           1  JeansA   42        1
3             111           1  ShirtA   40        0
4             111           2  JeansA   40        0
5             111           2  JeansA   44        1
6             111           2  JeansB   44        1
7             222           1  ShirtA   36        1
8             222           1  ShirtB   36        1
9             222           1  ShirtB   40        0
10            222           1  JeansA   40        0
11            222           2  JeansB   38        0
11            222           2  ShirtA   44        0
12            222           3  JeansB   36        0
```

Result:

```
   customernumber ordernumber article size returned changed
1             111           1  JeansA   40        1       0
2             111           1  JeansA   42        1       0
3             111           1  ShirtA   40        0       0
4             111           2  JeansA   40        0       0
5             111           2  JeansA   44        1       1
6             111           2  JeansB   44        1       0   
7             222           1  ShirtA   36        1       0
8             222           1  ShirtB   36        1       0
9             222           1  ShirtB   40        0       0
10            222           1  JeansA   40        0       0
11            222           2  JeansB   38        0       0
11            222           2  ShirtA   44        0       1
12            222           3  JeansB   36        0       0
```

Sorry for the confusion, I actually made a mistake in my example and filled the changed variable incorrectly. If you are still up helping me, I would appreciate it very much.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe don’t group by order number?

Comment: yeah, but then she'll have a problem because the same order could have multiple articles of the same kind with different sizes, and if one one them is returned, the second will be marked as exchanged, which is not true.

Comment: Could you explain why the `1` for `changed` in row 5 should be there? Shouldn't that be in row 4?

Comment: @Jaap: I added another part to the question, where I tried to be more precise about the problem. In the original version I actually made a mistake in the example result. In the original example the changed == 1 in row 4 actually shouldn't be there, since the same article in the same size had been ordered in order 1. It should only be marked with (changed == 1) if it is the same article but in a different size in the next order. Since in the second row JeansA has been orderer in size 42 it appears again in the second order and thus the article is not exchanged. Hope that cleared things up?

Comment: See the updated answer, HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New answer:**

A possible solution with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, changed := 0
   ][df[df, on = .(customernumber, ordernumber < ordernumber, article), nomatch = 0
        ][size != i.size & returned == 1, .SD[!i.size %in% size], by = .(customernumber, ordernumber, article)
          ][, .(customernumber, ordernumber, article, size = i.size)][, unique(.SD)]
     , on = .(customernumber, ordernumber, article, size), changed := 1][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     customernumber ordernumber article size returned changed
>  1:            111           1  JeansA   40        1       0
>  2:            111           1  JeansA   42        1       0
>  3:            111           1  ShirtA   40        0       0
>  4:            111           2  JeansA   40        0       0
>  5:            111           2  JeansA   44        1       1
>  6:            111           2  JeansB   44        1       0
>  7:            222           1  ShirtA   36        1       0
>  8:            222           1  ShirtB   36        1       0
>  9:            222           1  ShirtB   40        0       0
> 10:            222           1  JeansA   40        0       0
> 11:            222           2  JeansB   38        0       0
> 12:            222           2  ShirtA   44        0       1
> 13:            222           3  JeansB   36        0       0
> ```

**Old answer:**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[df[returned == 0][df[returned == 1]
                     , on = .(customernumber, article)
                     ][ordernumber != i.ordernumber]
   , on = .(customernumber, article, returned)
   , changed := i.returned
   ][, changed := replace(changed, is.na(changed), 0)][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     customernumber ordernumber article size returned changed
>  1:            111           1  JeansA   40        1       0
>  2:            111           1  JeansA   42        1       0
>  3:            111           1  ShirtA   40        0       0
>  4:            111           2  JeansA   42        0       1
>  5:            111           2  JeansB   44        1       0
>  6:            222           1  ShirtA   36        1       0
>  7:            222           1  ShirtB   36        1       0
>  8:            222           1  ShirtB   40        0       0
>  9:            222           1  JeansA   40        0       0
> 10:            222           2  JeansB   38        0       0
> 11:            222           2  ShirtA   44        0       1
> 12:            222           3  JeansB   36        0       0
> ```

Comment: Works like a charm on the example, thank you! Unfortunately I encountered one specific combination, where it doesn't seem to work:

df1 <- data.frame(customernumber = c("111", "111", "111", "111", "111"),
                  ordernumber = c("1", "2", "2", "2", "2"),
                  article = c("JeansA", "JeansA", "JeansA", "JeansA", "JeansA"),
                  size = c("39", "39", "38", "39", "38"),
                  returned = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1")

Comment: @Ditzgewizzle That's correct. All of those are returned, so for none of these orders the condition `returned == 0` holds. Consequently, none of them can be seen as a follow-up order.

Comment: @Ditzgewizzle glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You are working on more than one lag condition, so we need more than one `lag` commands to create that condition. We can then use `case_when` to create the `changed` column.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(customernumber, article) %>%
  mutate(lag_returned = lag(returned),
         lag_ordernumber = lag(ordernumber)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(changed = case_when(
    returned %in% "0" & 
      duplicated(article) & 
        lag_returned %in% "1" &
          ordernumber != lag_ordernumber ~ "1",
    TRUE                                 ~ "0"
  )) %>%
  select(-starts_with("lag"))

df2
# # A tibble: 12 x 6
#    customernumber ordernumber article size  returned changed
#    <fct>          <fct>       <fct>   <fct> <fct>    <chr>  
#  1 111            1           JeansA  40    1        0      
#  2 111            1           JeansA  42    1        0      
#  3 111            1           ShirtA  40    0        0      
#  4 111            2           JeansA  42    0        1      
#  5 111            2           JeansB  44    1        0      
#  6 222            1           ShirtA  36    1        0      
#  7 222            1           ShirtB  36    1        0      
#  8 222            1           ShirtB  40    0        0      
#  9 222            1           JeansA  40    0        0      
# 10 222            2           JeansB  38    0        0      
# 11 222            2           ShirtA  44    0        1      
# 12 222            3           JeansB  36    0        0
```

Comment: You answered my question perfectly fine! Thank you. Applying your code to the real data, I encountered one problem. If the same article in the same size appears in the next order before the actual changed article with a different size. I'll update the question accordingly!

Comment: @Ditzgewizzle It looks like you have a different criteria than your initial question. If you have a new question, ask a new question. Please do not modify you old question as it makes my answer looked "wrong". I don't have the time or obligation to update my answer if this generated the desired output to your original question, but if you have a new question with good reproducible example and clear explanation, I may have the time to look into it later.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right and I made the mistake in my example I gave you. I changed it back to the old version and added another example, where I tried to be more precise. It would be great if you still could have a look into it.